# How can we create our own news JSON API like provided on the newsapi.org website?

Tags: rest, api

How can I make my own custom APIs like we see on newsapi.org website

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest start looking into a framework.  Personally I use Laravel/Lumen this would give you all the tools to emulate that API.